# How to zoom in as much as on the iOS Maps application

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm using iOS 7.1 and I observe that i can zoom more on the Maps application than on mycapplication showing satellite maps.
Is it normal ?

I init my map in an UIViewController in the -viewDidLoad() method :

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]init];
[mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 125, 1024, 643)];
[mapView setRotateEnabled:NO];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
mapView.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:map];
```

[image: my app]

[image: Maps/Plans]
Thanx for your reply.

Comment: not everyone know what is Plans, can you provide screenshots/code?

Comment: Plans is the iOS application given by Apple!

Comment: Oh, sorry, can you please provide link to app store?

Comment: My application :http://imageshack.com/a/img198/4049/njmt.png and Plans equivalence http://imageshack.com/a/img834/5011/ayun.png

Comment: I misunderstand you because in english locale **Plans** names as **Maps**

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: -1 for non-programming question (with no details provided) -> wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Alexander, i've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to not be possible....